# Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit, Unity 7.4.0) stucks in splash screen after enabled gdm3

Tags: 16.04, gdm, display-manager

I am trying to set gdm display manager on fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 with unity 7.4.0
Installed and enabled gdm:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

After reboot PC stucks in splash screen. If I try <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I get:

> A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (xmin ysec / no limit).

When I enter in recovery mode, the in loading process I can notice errors:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]